# Include files and also copy them to output

Tags: jekyll

In a Jekyll powered page, I have a set of files located in:

```
_includes/stuff/
```

I put those files there so that I can `include` them in other Markdown pages using:

```
{% include stuff/example.txt %}
```

This works as expected.

However, I also want to copy those files to the generated page so that I can link to them and that people can follow those links to download them. But by definition, stuff stored in directories starting with an underscore are not copied by Jekyll.

Another approach also didn't work. I put the files in an own top folder called `stuff`. This copies the folder to the final site. However, I'm not able to include a file from this folder. It seems `include_relative` only allows including files below the current one. For example, the following don't work:

```
{% include_relative stuff/example.txt %}
{% include_relative /stuff/example.txt %}
{% include_relative ../stuff/example.txt %}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve including and copying at the same time?

Comment: What about using `include` instead of `include_relative`. I didn't try, but that would be my first attempt.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Doesn't work, I tried that first, see beginning of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works from index.html

```
{% include_relative example.txt %} for example.txt
{% include_relative stuff/example.txt %} for stuff/example.txt
{% include_relative /stuff/example.txt %} for stuff/example.txt
```

**stuff/example.txt**

```
class Toto
  def dototo
      myvar = "toto"
  end
end
```

**index.html**

```
{% assign codeurl = "stuff/example.txt" %}
{% highlight ruby %}
{% include_relative {{codeurl}} %}
{% endhighlight %}
<a href="{{codeurl}}">link to code</a>

if codeurl == "/stuff/example.txt" this generates a link relative to site root
this may need {{site.baseurl}} prepended if your site is not at the root 
of a domain (eg: user.github.io/repository)
<a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{codeurl}}">link to code</a>
```

For security reasons, this will not work :

```
{% include_relative ../stuff/example.txt %}
Just to avoid directory traversal
{% include_relative ../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/pwd %}
```

If you want to put you files in **_includes/stuff** you will need to do an `include: [ /_includes ]` in _config.yml, that will include all files in _includes as static files. Not very clean as you cannot filter subdiretories like `include: [ /_includes/stuff ]` to import only your stuff files.

**Note** : a dirty trick allows you to import only `_includes/stuff/*.txt` but I think it's really dirty.

```
# _config.yml
include:
  - "_includes"
  - "stuff"
  - "*.txt"

exclude:
  - "_includes/*.*"
```

Comment: Ha! This **is** a dirty trick, but incredibly helpful!!!  Short version is I have a submodule setup in my `_data` directory, and need to keep a couple of files from there.  This is the only way I could get this to work without having to just duplicate the submodule again, thanks :)